# Smart contracts work when deployed with Remix, but not Web3j

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, web3j

I have a web3j call to a smart contract `ecrecover()` function and I need to pass the `V` value. However I'm unsure as to how to convert the `V` value to a `BigInteger`.

Web3j:

```
aVerifier.verify("Kieran", "Hughes", signature.getV(), signature.getR(), signature.getS()).send();
```

`signature.getV()` is not accepted here as it is of the type `Byte` and must be `BigInteger`.

*Problem solved:*

Remix handles basic user input. Web3j requires conversion of Byte to BigInteger

```
BigInteger.valueOf(signature.getV())
```

Comment: Where is your web3 code?

Comment: @goodvibration I've added in the part of the Web3j that I think is causing the problem. When using Remix, I pass the String value output by the println, however in the Web3j call I'm passing just the HexMessage value.

Comment: @goodvibration turns out I was passing the wrong value of V in my attempt to convert it from Byte to BigInt